# Program failed to compile

Tags: c++

Here is my code. I am using Dev-C++ 4.9.8.0 and I can not figure out why this wont compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int  n;    // Number to test for prime-ness
    int  i;    // Loop counter
    int  is_prime = true; // Boolean flag...
                          // Assume true for now.

    // Get a number form the keyboard.

    cout << "Enter a number and press ENTER: ";
    cin >> n;

    // Test for prime by checking for divisibility 
    // by all whole numbers from 2 to sqrt(n).

    i = 2;
    while (i <= sqrt(n)) {  // While i is <= sqrt(n),
         if (n % i == 0)         // If i divides n, 
             is_prime = false;   //    n is not prime.
         i++;
 }

 // Print results

 if (is_prime)
     cout << "Number is prime." << endl;
 else
     cout << "Number is not prime." << endl;

 system("PAUSE");   
 return 0;
}
```

Im getting various error messages about overloading. Can someone please help me figure out why its not compiling correctly.

Comment: Try posting the error messages you're seeing.

Comment: For one thing, `<stdlib.h>` should either be `<cstdlib>`, or you should bracket that include in `extern "C"`

Comment: I am not sure but `int  is_prime = true;` this legal ???.. how you can give string value to int ???

Comment: For another, `using namespace std;` is a terrible idea in general and can lead to errors of the type you're describing because of collisions with commonly-used symbol names in `std::`.

Comment: @Ashish `int is_prime= true;` is absolutely legal.

Comment: Compiles and runs with g++ 4.7.3 under ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: @Ashish `true` and `false` are constants that can be promoted to `int` implicitly, though, it would be better if `is_prime` was declared as a `bool`.

Comment: Dev-C++ 4.9.8.0  is 10 years old. Please update your compiler.

Comment: Are you trying to compile any other code with this? If there's another main() somewhere that could explain the overloading error.

Comment: [Warning] In function 'int main()':

Comment: @ZacHowland Thanks.. I could have still build an enumerator & sorted out this like `enum bool { true,false }` some sort of this in dev c++

Comment: line 22 call of overloaded 'sqrt(int&)' is ambiguous

Comment: line 163 C:\Dev-Cpp\include\math.h   candidates are: double sqrt(double)

Comment: line 465 C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\cmath    long double std::sqrt(long

Comment: I tried using #include <cstdlib> and still gave the above error messages

Comment: line 461 C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\cmath     float std::sqrt(float)

Comment: C:\Dev-Cpp\Makefile.win     [Build Error] [prime1.o]Error 1

Comment: @Ashish `enum bool { ... }` is invalid in C++ as `bool` is a keyword for a boolean type.  `bool`, `true`, and `false` are all reserved words in C++.

Comment: @ZacHowland that was just for understanding takeit bool1 if you want

Comment: @Ashish In that case, yes, you could have `enum BOOLEAN { FALSE = 0, TRUE }` and something like `int i = TRUE` would compile with no problems.

Comment: @user3150065 - DevCpp is *ancient*. For your own sake, please switch to a modern compiler. I'll assume you're on Windows, so I would go with Visual Studio or clang. You may be wondering: "why should I care that my compiler is ancient?", the answer is that you are stuck with C++98 (which is a terrible language now that we know better). C++11 "feels like a completely different language" to quote the gurus, it looks and feels much much nicer, it's harder to write bugs, and it's easier to be productive. Modern compilers enable you to use all of the new features.

Answer (score 8):

As predicted, the error is a result of a symbol clash between an `std::sqrt` and `sqrt`, due to your use of `using namespace std;`.

The header `cmath` has a function called `std::sqrt`, and the symbol name `sqrt` is being imported into your namespace because of your `using namespace std;`.  Even though you are not including `math.h`, for some reason your compiler is importing that header as well, and `math.h` defines a `sqrt` function.

The compiler is complaining that it does not know which `sqrt` to use.

The correct solution to this is to *not use* `using namespace std;`.  See also: [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

In your particular case, you can replace `using namespace std;` with the following:

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
```

to avoid typing `std::` in front of these all the time.

To be honest the compiler should not be including `math.h`, and as others have pointed out, using a 10+ year old compiler is just silly.  Use a modern compiler.

**Edit:** Also, please, never again post half a dozen comments in a row to communicate a multi-line error message.  Just edit your original post.

Comment: But if you want to use namespace std, you can try either `::sqrt(n)`, `std::sqrt(n)` or `sqrt<>(n)`.

Comment: Another alternative is to not use `sqrt` at all, which would eliminate the need for `cmath` altogether.  [Example](http://ideone.com/ajXHEK)

Comment: If I could give you another +1 for the note about posting errors, I would!

Answer (score 0):

This compiles fine in gcc.

Although thre are some things you can improve like <del>not including `#include <stdlib.h>`</del> including `stdlib` instead of `stdlib.h` and `making is_prime` `bool`.

> line 22 call of overloaded 'sqrt(int&)' is ambiguous

<del>try `sqrt<int>(n)` or `sqrt((int) n)`</del>

@Andrey gives you the answer: use `::sqrt(n)` or `std::sqrt(n)` or include `math.h` instead of `cmath`. The best is still as he suggests: don't use `using namespace std;`.

My advice: switch to a more mainstream compiler like gcc, clang or Visual Studio. They better conform with the standard.

> The book i am using uses Dev-C++

i don't want to be mean but switch to another book two. I wouldn't trust a book that makes you include `stdlib.h`. It's a header from the time that C wasn't standardized yet. So... yeah... switch the book...

Comment: Omitting the include of `<stdlib.h>` is not an improvement while the call to `system` remains.

Comment: oh yeah sorry didn't see the `system` call

Comment: @remyabel: Actually it is in C++11.

Comment: I know, but i also know that a standard compliant compiler wouldn't give this kind of error. That's why I said "try".

Comment: @bolov The comments of the questioner show that it is no template but a overload problem due to `using namespace std`

Comment: Im going to try it in Visual Studio. The book i am using uses Dev-C++.

Comment: Microsoft Visual studio express is free and has moderate C++11 support.

Comment: @kfsone Yeah, it's really frustrating that is behind with the C++11 standard. I am implementing a gcc-VS library written in C++11 and VS really limits me in what I want to do :(